# Proof that generalized Laplacian is essentially self-adjoint (Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators)

Tags: hilbert-spaces, schwartz-distributions

According to Proposition 2.33 in [Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators](https://link.springer.com/book/9783540200628) each symmetric generalized Laplacian $H$ is essentially self-adjoint. This is an immediate consequence of the fact that
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\overline{H^*}=H^\dagger,
\end{equation}
where $H^*$ is the formal adjoint of $H$ and $H^\dagger$ is the (Hilbert space) adjoint. Unfortunately I can not quite follow the proof of (1):

I feel like the proof is not quite complete$^1$, but maybe thats just because I dont fully understand it: Here are two parts I am struggling with (the full proof is inserted as an image further below):

> It is clear that $D(H^\dagger) =\mathcal D:= \{s \in L^2(M,E):H^*s\in L^2(M,E)\}$,
> where $H^*s$ is defined in the distributional sense.

What does it mean that $H^*s$ is defined in the distributional sense?

> We see that $P^*H^* = H^*P^*$ on $\Gamma^{-\infty}(M, E)$, and in particular on $\mathcal D$.

Why can we view $\mathcal D$ as a subset of $\Gamma^{-\infty}(M,E)$?

---

$^1$ As far as I understand we show that $D(H^\dagger)\subseteq D(\overline{H^*})$ and $\forall s\in D(H^\dagger):\overline{H^*}(s)=H^\dagger(s)$ - but we just seem to assume that $H^*$ is closable. Aren't we missing a proof for that? Also even if we can show that $H^*$ is closable, don't we need to show that $D(\overline{H^*})\subseteq D(H^\dagger)$?

---

[image]

Comment: In that book the background manifold is compact and without boundary.    To see how the formal adjoints  and analytic adjoints are related chect section 10.4 of these notes. https://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Lectures.pdf

Answer (score 1):

> I feel like the proof is not quite complete: As far as I understand we show that $D(H^\dagger)\subseteq D(\overline{H^*})$ and $\forall s\in D(H^\dagger):\overline{H^*}(s)=H^\dagger(s)$ - but we just seem to assume that $H^*$ is closable. Aren't we missing a proof for that? Also even if we can show that $H^*$ is closable, don't we need to show that $D(\overline{H^*})\subseteq D(H^\dagger)$?

- The formal adjoint $H^*$ is closable, because the Hilbert space adjoint $H^\dagger$ is a closed extension: $H$ is defined on a dense subspace of $\mathcal H$, so the adjoint $H^\dagger$ is well-defined and adjoints are always closed. Furthermore it is not difficult to see that $H^\dagger$ is an extension of $H^*$: If $s=|s\rangle \in\Gamma(E)$, then $\langle s|\circ H=\langle H^*s|\in \Gamma(E)^*$ is in the topological dual and hence $s$ is in the domain of $H^\dagger$ and $H^*s=H^\dagger s$.
- The closure is the smallest closed extension. Hence $H^\dagger \subseteq \overline{H^*}$ already implies that $H^\dagger = \overline{H^*}$.

> What does it mean that $H^∗s$ is defined in the distributional sense?

I will use Dirac notation: I think that $H^*|s\rangle=\langle s|H\in L(\Gamma(E),\mathbb C)$ and by $H^∗s\in\mathcal H$ we mean that $H^∗s\in\Gamma(E)^*\cong\mathcal H^*\cong\mathcal H$. Then $\mathcal D$ is indeed the domain of $H^\dagger$.

> Why can we view $\mathcal D$ as a subset of $\Gamma^{-\infty}(M,E)$?

No need to worry about this. Just note that $PH=HP$ implies that $H^\dagger P^\dagger=P^\dagger H^\dagger$ on the domain of $H^\dagger$ and hence and we get
$$H^*s_n=H^\dagger P^\dagger_{1/n}s=P^\dagger_{1/n}H^\dagger s=P^\dagger_{1/n}H^\dagger s\underset{n\to\infty}{\to} H^\dagger s$$
where we used that $P^*$ is the heat kernel of the Laplacian $H^*$ such that we can apply Lemma 2.34 to $P^*$ instead of $P$.